# Javascript XHR request catch HTTP CONNECT errors

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm using Charles to disturb the XHR requests and noticed that the 
xhr.onerror callback is not being called when the HTTP CONNECT request has failed.

This is not the case when the HTTP POST request has failed.

Does anyone know how to listen to such errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "_Charles_"? What do you mean with "_disturb the XHR requests_"?

Comment: Charles proxy: https://www.charlesproxy.com/ using Throttling with reliability of 50% and stability of 50% over https

Comment: Good question! Although I feel it's impossible to catch `CONNECT` error. `CONNECT` is a method to open HTTP/HTTPS tunnel, it's a browser behaviour working on TCP level ("Hi proxy, please open a raw TCP connection to XXX, and forward any bytes I write.")